# Gensim v3.6.0 Word2Vec DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `wv` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self instead)

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

I was using Gensim 3.6.0 for loading a pre-trained Word2Vec and it showed the following error while calling `model.wv`.

```
/anaconda/envs/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `wv` (Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self instead).
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Here is my code sample

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/path/to/file/my-vec-300d-v2', binary=False)
print(model.wv['hello'].shape)
print(model.wv['hello'])
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message actually tells us using the object itself i.e. `model` rather than `model.wv`.

```
print(model['hello'].shape) # instead of model.wv['hello'].shape which is deprecated
print(model['hello']) # instead of model.wv['hello'] which is deprecated
```

Comment: Yes, if you've loaded something as an instance of `KeyedVectors`, there's no need to try to access it's sub-property `.wv`. Just do your operations on the object itself.